# Matlab, Automatic Function Start

Tags: matlab, automation

I have a function with three inputs. I will change inputs and record the outcomes. So, If I have all the inputs in a excel, what I can do to automize things?
What I have?
A Function of Matlab, (lets say) 1000 different input for that function
What I want? 
I want this function to work for every input and record to a excel the outputs without user intervention.

Do you have any idea how can I do that?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [xlsread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html) and [xlswrite](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlswrite.html). Simply write a script to:

1. Load your inputs from the Excel file using `xlsread`
2. Loop through the inputs, calling your function for each set of inputs and storing the result in an array
3. Write the results to an output file using `xlswrite`